# Access 'post' data using JavaScript or check which submit button was used to submit the form

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Consider a simple form with 2 submit buttons

```
<form method="post">
 <button type="submit" name="command" value="cancel">Cancel Order</button>
 <button type="submit" name="command" value="proceed">Save Order</button>
</form>
```

Once submitted, the server will know which submit button was used to submit the form by checking the value for `command`. Great!

In this case, I am using the `onsubmit` event handler of the form to preprocess and send the form data via AJAX. Like this: `<form method="post" onsubmit="return ajaxSubmit(this);">`

I'm using this `ajaxSubmit` function as a general way to check through any supplied form's elements and send the data via Ajax instead. This works fine for determining the value of text fields, if checkboxes are "checked", which radio is selected in a group, etc. The only thing it seems to get wrong (because I'm not sure how to check this) is which submit button was used to submit the form. i.e There is nothing in `myForm["command"]` to tell which of the 2 command buttons was actually used.

Instead, is there a way to access the same 'post' data that the server receives with JavaScript before it is sent?

Otherwise, is this just a flaw I need to work around? What's the best way?

**Edit:**
Since all modern browsers will pass the name/value of the button used to submit the form (along with the other relevant parts like which option is selected from a group, checked checkbox name/values, etc.) can anyone explain why there is no way to access this data directly before it is sent to the server? Is there a reason why we shouldn't be able to?

Comment: Perhaps I have misunderstood, but if you are using AJAX to send form data to the server, why use 'post' at all? Also, to identify which submit button was pressed, can't you just supply ID properties and pass them to the AJAX routine?

Comment: The Ajax routine is a general purpose function called 'ajaxSubmit' which takes a JavaScript 'form' object representing an HTML form tag and it's elements. In many cases, I'm using it to replace regular form submits (and page refreshes) with Ajax instead. I like that I can submit Ajax via post and expect the same results server side.

Comment: Note that if you use `button` instead of `input type="submit"`, older versions of IE will send **all** the button values, not just the one you clicked.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Instead, is there a way to access the same 'post' data that the server receives with JavaScript before it is sent?

Not that exact data, no.

The usual way to know which `submit` button was pressed is (unfortunately) to attach `click` handlers to the buttons and have them set a variable (or the value of a `hidden` field), which you can then check in your `submit` event handler.

Since you're using old-style DOM0 event handler attributes, probably the `hidden` field fits better with what you're doing:

```
<form method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="submitclicked" value="">
 <button type="submit" name="command" value="cancel" onclick="submitClick(this);">Cancel Order</button>
 <button type="submit" name="command" value="proceed" onclick="submitClick(this);">Save Order</button>
</form>
```

...where `submitClick` looks like this:

```
function submitClick(button) {
    button.form.submitclicked.value = button.value;
}
```

...but I do recommend looking into using DOM2-style event handlers instead, or at least attaching DOM0 handlers in code blocks, as you can avoid creating global functions, share data without creating global variables, etc.

---

Just to be clear, you don't have to specify an `onclick` attribute on every element, the only reason I did that above is because you were using DOM0 handlers.

The better way to handle it is with event bubbling. Since the `click` event bubbles up to the form from its descendant controls, including the submit buttons, you can hook the event on the form and then look to see if it occurred on a submit button and, if so, what that button's `value` is.

For instance, here with a DOM0 handler, attached dynamically to the form, which will alert the value of the submit button clicked:

```
var form = document.getElementById("theForm");
form.onclick = function(e) {
  // Get the event
  e = e || window.event;

  // Did it originate in an input[type=submit]?
  if (e.target.tagName === "INPUT" &&
      e.target.type === "submit") {
    // Yes
    alert(e.target.value);
  }
};
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ucoboq/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ucoboq/1/edit)

Or using DOM2 handlers on any modern browser (not IE8 or earlier, but it would be easy to add `attachEvent` for those, which does much the same thing `addEventListener` does [and predates it]):

```
document.getElementById("theForm").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  // Did it originate in an input[type=submit]?
  if (e.target.tagName === "INPUT" &&
      e.target.type === "submit") {
    // Yes
    alert(e.target.value);
  }
}, false);
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ucoboq/2) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ucoboq/2/edit)

Or using a library to make it easier (here it's jQuery, but most of them have this feature, which is called *event delegation*):

```
$("#theForm").delegate("input[type=submit]", "click", function() {
  alert(this.value);
  return false;
});
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ucoboq/3) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ucoboq/3/edit) (I'm using [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate) there because I like the clarity; with recent versions of jQuery, you *could* use the hyper-overloaded [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on), but it's less clear. If you choose to, note that the order of arguments is different.)

The point here being that it's not complicated, difficult, or particularly cumbersome.

Re your ending question of your edit:

> ...can anyone explain why there is no way to access this data directly before it is sent to the server?

Probably not, no. It's important to understand that a lot of this stuff just evolved. The submit button's value being sent with the form is an HTML thing, apparently when doing the DOM HTML forms module, it just didn't occur to anyone to say "Hey, we should have a property on the form that only exists during the form submission event that tells you what submitted the form." It probably *should* have occurred to someone, but apparently, it didn't.

Comment: Thanks. This is about the only (maybe best) way I have found to work around the issue.

Comment: @Matthew: I've added further examples and addressed (to *some* extent) the question in your edit.

Comment: Thanks again. This keeps the form reasonably intact (all we're really doing is adding an extra hidden field) and doing some event handling to make it all work.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution is to use a radio button instead of a submit button (you will have to design the radio to look as a button, though).

After submitting, the value of the field should be the one that was clicked. You can fetch the selected option by using jQuery's `$("[name=command]:selected]")`, or `$("#theForm").serialize()`

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="return ajaxSubmit(this);" id="theForm">
 <input type="radio" name="command" value="cancel" id="cancel" onClick="document.getElementById('theForm').submit();">
 <label for="cancel">Cancel Order</label>

 <input type="radio" name="command" value="proceed" id="proceed" onClick="document.getElementById('theForm').submit();">
 <label for="proceed">Save Order</label>
</form>
```

Comment: Good "outside the box" thinking. I hadn't considered something like this.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can work this around by DELETING the other button, the one that that was not clicked. After that, you can run jQuery's serialize(), or access the value of the button that is left by any other means.

The code would be:

```
<form method="post">
 <button type="submit" id=cancel name="command" value="cancel" onclick="document.getElementByid('submit').remove();submitClick(this);">Cancel Order</button>
 <button type="submit" id=submit name="command" value="proceed" onclick="document.getElementByid('cancel').remove();submitClick(this);">Save Order</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

All reasonable, but if you're going to go as far as attaching click handlers on all your submit buttons, it makes less sense to go through the hoops of the submit capability to manage your submission details.

Just make it so that the click handlers trigger a form submit while passing sufficient contextual information into the mix. Wait, click handlers typically tell you the source of the click already (there's your contextual information), especially if using some jQuery-ish framework.

So instead of:

```
<form onsubmit="doSubmit()" ...>
<input type="submit" onclick="updateSourceTo('cancel');" ... />
<input type="submit" onclick="updateSourceTo('submit');" ... />
```

Use:

```
<form ...>
<input type="button" onclick="doSubmit('cancel');" ... />
<input type="button" onclick="doSubmit('submit');" ... />
```

Or, if you'll be detecting the source by looking at the click event target:

```
<form ...>
<input type="button" onclick="handleSubmitButtonClick();" ... />
<input type="button" onclick="handleSubmitButtonClick();" ... />
```

For the nitty-gritty details of handleSubmitButtonClick, I should mention [form.submit()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp) and things like jQuery's [event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/).

I admit that keeping with the submit-onsubmit paradigm promotes a certain purism to form handling, but IMO you're already stepping into non-purist lands with the use of two submit buttons.